# 'Converting varchar to data type numeric' error after successful conversion to decimal(18,2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have a temporary table I'm using for parsing, `#rp`.

`#rp` contains an `nvarchar(max)` column, `#rp.col8`, which holds positive and negative numbers to two decimal places of precision e.g. `1234.26'.

I'm able to run the following query and get out a set of converted values out:

```
select * from
(
    select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),rp.col8) as PARSEAMT
    from #rp

    where
    --#rp filtering criteria
)q
```

However, when I try to query for `PARSEAMT = 0` in the following manner, I get the standard '8114, Error converting data type varchar to numeric.':

```
select * from
(
    select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),col8) as PARSEAMT
    from #rp

    where
    --#rp filtering criteria
)q  
where q.PARSEAMT = 0
```

Without that `where` clause, the query runs fine and generates the expected values.

I've also tried other clauses like `where q.PARSEAMT = 0.00` and `where q.PARSEAMT = convert(decimal(18,2),0)`.

What am I doing wrong in my comparison?

Comment: What does SELECT MAX(PARSEAMT), MIN(PARSEAMT) yield?

Comment: Aaron : MAX() returns 328.90, MIN() returns -111.46

Comment: Well I can't reproduce the problem, so there must be some factor that isn't revealed in the question. Can you show CREATE TABLE #rp? Are you sure all values in col8 are valid decimal values? If so, why is the column nvarchar(max) instead of using the right data type in the first place?

Comment: #RP is a table of something like 50 NVARCHAR(MAX) columns; it's essentially something I built to hold a hierarchical file structure in a sort of entity-attribute-value table before I upload them into something more sane. I've just checked with some regex, and I'm pretty sure they all fit into valid decimal format. The weird part is that I -can- convert them into valid numeric(18,2) values using the subquery... but when I try to compare the converted value, it generates the conversion error.

Comment: Without a simpler repro and sample data to reproduce the problem, you're going to have a hard time having anyone else decipher the problem for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, very true. I'll have to try generating a set of publishable test data, which might take some time. Can you think of any reason why that encapsulating subquery doesn't work? Additionally: I can insert PARSEAMT into a table variable with a column of decimal(18,2) without any trouble, and doing a SELECT on the table variable for PARSEAMT = 0 produces usable results. I think I can work that into a solution, but I'm mostly curious as to why I might have to jump through these hoops to get there.

Comment: Not sure, won't be able to really postulate until I can see more of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest you select PARSEAMT into another temp-table/table-variable but I can see you've already done that from your comments.

Out of interest what does the following yield?

```
select 
    col8
from
    #rp
where
    -- ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid 
    -- numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0. Valid numeric data types 
    -- include the following:
    isnumeric(col8) <> 1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I ran an ISNUMERIC() check on that column before with clear results. I'll give it another run when I get up tomorrow.

Comment: Your query returns zero results after I factor in my previous criteria. Keep in mind that ISNUMERIC() will return 1 as long as the input can be converted to -any- numeric type, regardless of whether it's the one you're trying to use in the end.